# Android Studio- Play Sound on button tap WEAR

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio, wear-os

I am making an app for Android Wear Devices that don't have speakers. For now I am testing. How can I make it so when you tap "button1" it does said function that plays, say an MP3 file FROM THE PHONES SPEAKER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to build out a companion phone app to play the sound, and trigger it from Wear, probably using the [Message API](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html). The [FindMyPhone sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FindMyPhone/) (linked from that doc page) is probably a good place to start, as it's doing something quite similar to your requirements: playing a sound on the phone, triggered by an action on the watch.